# How To Summon ArmorStands With Blocks On There Heads In 1.9?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Tried:

```
/summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {Equipment:[{},{},{},{},{id:coal_ore}]}
```

That did not work. It just spawned without the block on its head.

Also tried:

```
/summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {Equipment:[{},{},{},{},{id:16}]}
```

That did not work either.

Answer (score 1):

In 1.9, the `Equipment` tag no longer exists. Instead, `HandItems` and `ArmorItems` have replaced it.

`HandItems` contains two record, the first is the mainhand and the second is the offhand. `ArmorItems` contains four records, in order: feet, legs, chest, helmet.

```
/summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~ {ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:"minecraft:coal_ore"}]}
```